# MySQL '%' hostname wildcard

Tags: mysql, permissions

I've used the following to grant all privileges on `mydb` to `myusername`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* to myusername @'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

I thought that the `%` is a wildcard for all hosts. It worked for a while, but then I had some permission errors when the user tried to access the db from the same machine. I added the following lines:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* to myusername @'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* to myusername @'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

And now the user can access the database.

What does the `%` stand for? Is there a wildcard for all hosts?

Comment: I'm not sure whether a space is allowed before `@`.  Anyway, from the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html): `The simple form user_name is a synonym for user_name@'%'.`  So, just omit the `@'hostname` part.

Comment: Thanks @dezso, care to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html), two things to mention:

- not sure whether a space is allowed before `@` (not declared explicitly, but the *user* string takes the `user_name@host_name` form - and since this is a string, one can expect that the space is not allowed)
- and, better, if you want to grant privileges to a user on all hosts, you can simply omit the `@hostname` part completely.